# Vue.js hook on created event only once for a vue component

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, vue-component

**Question**

I have an issue where `created` event hook keep being called. Is there any sort of hook-once for this kind of even, like "first-created" or "first-mounted"? If possible, no junk code to attach for each component.

**POI**

Here is an example that shows how the `created` hook keeps being called if you switch from page "foo" to "bar" (you will need to inspect the page to see the log).

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2f4bbcv7/8/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <!-- use router-link component for navigation. -->
    <!-- specify the link by passing the `to` prop. -->
    <!-- `<router-link>` will be rendered as an `<a>` tag by default -->
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <!-- route outlet -->
  <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>', created: function() { console.log('foo created'); } };
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>', created: function() { console.log('bar created'); } };

const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
});

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: `created` is called each time the component is mounted. What is the use case you would require a `one-time` hook for?

Comment: I am using Vuex and my "Price" page is calling a price list through my REST API (Laravel). On created I want to call my action, which asynchronously fetch my prices, and this action is calling my mutators that fill my "priceList" state to an array of prices. Then, the component responsible for displaying the price in a certain maner do a v-for on this variable (that I exposed through a `computed` on my price component). I whish there is a clean way to not constantly call my action every time my price component is created.

Answer (score 5):

Consider wrapping your `<router-view></router-view>` with `<keep-alive></keep-alive>`, so that when your route changes, the component for the routes isn't recreated: the created hook will only be called once when it is created initially.

```
<router-view>
  {({ Component }) => (
    <keep-alive>
      <Component />
    </keep-alive>
  )}
</router-view>
```